# Dailymotion API - set publication date and end date of video

Tags: upload, request, httprequest, dailymotion-api

is there any possibility to set the release date and the end date of a video?
I cannot find any request to do this (`start_date` and `end_date` is not what I am searching for, because it is only for live-streams).

I know that it is possible to set those two parameters when you are accepted as official.

http://s14.directupload.net/images/141029/3msfkrvc.png

I want to set the three values in the second box which is possible if the video is marked as private and the account is official. Is it possible to set those values with a normal Request (e. g. something like `https://api.dailymotion.com/video/VIDEOID?private=1&publication_start=...`) or was this not implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mailed a bit with their support.

It is currently not possible / only possible for few people with special contracts but there is a chance that they will implement it soon.